# Eagle Cad: How to get copper on both layers for a pin header

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, via

I am making a PCB for prototyping, I need solder pads for a male header on the top and bottom layers. In my previous PCB, I had SMD's and pin header pads on the top layer, Its always better to solder the pins on the other side, unfortunately no pads on the bottom layer for the header. I was also thinking about adding vias 
What should I do on the software to add pads on the bottom layer?
or Should I jut tell the vendor to add plated holes?

[image]

-Thanks 
Sandeep

Comment: In Eagle, if you make a through hole pad on a 2 layer PCB, it automatically makes the pad as a plated through hole with pads on top as well as bottom layer. However if you are making a single layer board, then you will get pad only on solder side.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not mention how many Layers your PCB is going to have, we have two scenarios.

If you got only a 1 layer PCB, then the best solution is to put the SMD parts on one side and the Pins on the other, so you can easily solder them to the pads.
Side view on PCB:
[image: Mounting the Pins on the others side of the PCB]

This is obviously the best option as long as the parts on the other side are almost of the same height. Depending on how the PCB is going to be used, you might want to add legs.

Since your picture just shows the layers top (red) and pads (green), but no bottom layer (blue) make sure its checked and therefor visible (you might want to turn of the top layer, when routing the bottom layer).

Afterwards you should check whether you got the right library for the Pin Headers. There are definetly ones with pads on both sides of the PCB, for instace in the standard library "pinhead".

If you place a via in eagle (2 layer PCB) you always have connections on both sides.
Make sure to check the "via" option if the vendor has one, because they are not always added by default.

**EDIT:**

I tested it in eagle and there is a connection between top and bottom layer of the PCB over the pinhead:

[image]

So if you order correctly, then there should be a connection between both layers over the pads on both sides. Just use the rule checks from eagle to make sure everything is connected (run ratsnest and turn off all layers except "Unrouted").

Comment: I am doing a two layer PCB. So do i need to place vias ? or ask the vendor to give plates on the bottom layer aswell?

Comment: If you hand in a 2 layer PCB then you should get pads on both sides. For the connection question see the edit to the original answer...